# Time conversion with moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am trying to send a date and time to the server and check if the time sent is between a certain range for the date that was sent. As an example I am trying to send the date and time March 15th 4pm PST (2021-03-15T23:00:33.000Z) to the server(set to UTC) and see if it is within the range 12am to 3:30 pm for that date. I am using moment.js to do the conversion using the code below

```
// This creates the moment object of the date sent from the client in PST which has an offset of 480
const clientSelectedDate = moment("2021-03-15T23:00:33.000Z").utcOffset(480);
// Getting start of the day sent by client
const currentDay = clientSelectedDate.clone().set({ hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0 });
// Setting start of the range
const startTime = currentDay.clone().set({ hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0 });
// Setting end of the range
const endTime = currentDay.clone().set({ hours: 15, minutes: 30, seconds: 0 });

const checkInBetween = startTime.isBefore(clientSelectedDate) && clientSelectedDate.isSameOrBefore(endTime);
```

the variable checkInBetween seems to return true. When I checked the value of clientSelectedDate using *clientSelectedDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm a")* I got the time as 15-03-2021 3:00 pm instead of the expected 15-03-2021 4:00 pm. I tried getting the milliseconds of the time 1615849200301 and checking them in a browser in PST and the server but they still showed a difference of 1 hour between them. I am using new Date().getTimezoneOffset() to get the 480 value that I send to the server. Any help with figuring out this issue would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- PST may be 480 (UTC-8), but Pacific Time switches between PST (UTC-8) and PDT (UTC-7) for daylight saving time.   Setting `utcOffset(480)` ignores this and places all values in UTC-8 *without DST*.
- The example you give `2021-03-15T23:00:33.000Z` is 7 hours from 4pm, not 8.  (23 - 16 = 7).  This is correct for Pacific time because daylight saving time started at 2am (Pacfic) on 2021-03-15, but it is not correct when setting a fixed offset of `480`.  That is the source of the discrepancy.
- You said:

  > ... When I checked the value of currentDay using currentDay.format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm a") I got the time as 15-03-2021 3:00 pm ...

  That can't happen.  Your code explicitly sets `currentDay`'s time to `00:00:00`.